# How can i fix this message decoder/encoder?

Tags: javascript

Uhm so basically this is a script for encoding and decoding a message in a webpage using JS. When i decode a message it just returns "undefined(first letter of message)undefinedundefined.....". I know the code is messy, wrote this at like 3 am. Please help. Can't find the problem, pretty new to JS.

```js
let dstring = "";
let estring = "";
let letter = "";
let letternum = 0;
let decodedtext = "";
let encodedtext = "";
let currentdt = "";
let currentcharat = 0;

const encoded = [
  "lsdjf",
  "flwek",
  "sdlfj",
  "pjnse",
  "dsfnn",
  "dsnfe",
  "sjndv",
  "sdfew",
  "sdfjn",
  "sfnkh",
  "ådpfk",
  "qpwkd",
  "sorif",
  "efjnf",
  "pijgn",
  "sijfb",
  "feuwh",
  "renfv",
  "soduh",
  "osdnv",
  "ksdjn",
  "tonrn",
  "frjng",
  "fjenw",
  "fnkrj",
  "vrejl",
  "fgwei"
];
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

function find(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
    if (input === encoded[i]) {
      //alert(alphabet[i]); (for debugging)
      return alphabet[i];
    }
  }
}

function encode() {
  estring = prompt("enter a string to encode, can only include non capital letters A-Z or SPACE");
  for (i = 0; i < estring.length; i++) {
    letter = estring.charAt(i);
    if (letter.charCodeAt(0) === 32) {
      letternum = 26;
    } else {
      letternum = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 97
    }
    encodedtext = encodedtext + encoded[letternum];
  }
  alert(encodedtext)
}

function decode() {
  decodedtext = "";
  dstring = prompt("enter a string to decode");
  for (l = 0; l < dstring.length / 5; l++) {
    currentdt = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      currentdt = currentdt + dstring.charAt(l * i);
    }
    decodedtext = decodedtext + find(currentdt)
  }
  alert(decodedtext);
}

encode();
decode();
```

So as I said, when trying to decode something like "soduhksdjnsoduhundefinedsdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn" (which would translate to "code") it just returns undefinedCundefinedundefined...... I've tried a number of methods, my code worked in a very different way at first with the character "|" marking where a letter ends and the character "§" marking when the message ended.

Comment: Can you explain your encode and decode function ?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the the string "soduhksdjnsoduhundefinedsdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn" from? When you call your `encode` function with `code` as an input you get `sdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn` not what you mentioned. That string you provided also has a length of 44 which isn't a multiple of 5 which is what your encode function produces, so it's not a valid input.

Comment: your find(currentdt) in the decode function doesn't find the text that you pass in the prompt, so when you concatenate decodedtext = decodedtext + find(currentdt), it gives you many undefined,do this instead : function find(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
    if (input === encoded[i]) {
      //alert(alphabet[i]); (for debugging)
      return alphabet[i];
    }
  }
  return false 
} and then do this in the decode function : if (find(currentdt)){decodedtext = decodedtext + find(currentdt)}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `soduhksdjnsoduhundefinedsdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn` isn't a valid input for your decoder, it has `undefined` in its text. It's not clear how you produced this with an input of `code` as the encoder actually produces an output of `sdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn` for `code`.

Next, your indexing logic isn't correct:

```
dstring.charAt(l*i)
```

When `l` is `0`, you'll be doing `dstring.charAt(0)` for all 5 iterations of your inner loop. When `l` is 1, you'll get the first 5 characters of your input, when it's `2` however, you'll then be accessing indexes `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`. As you can see, you're repeating indexes. This leads to you constructing invalid `currentdt` values that when passed to `find(currentdt)`, can't be found in the `encoded` array that `find` searches, leading to the `undefined` values.

What you really want to be doing is offseting `i` with `+` based on the number of chunks you've already computed (`l*5`):

It should be:

```
dstring.charAt((l*5)+i)
```

In addition to this, your `alphabet` array/string is missing a space   character. When you run `find()` with the space encoding  `alphabet` for the space `fgwei` encoding you'll end up searching for the character at index 26, which doesn't exist currently. You should make the 26th character a space for your decoder to work correctly with space characters. In addition to this, there is no need to turn your string into an array here. Indexing with bracket notation `[i]` works fine on strings:

```js
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ';
                           ^--- space added here at the 26th index.
```

Lastly, your loop variables created with `for(l = 0; ...)` and `for(i = 0; ...)` mean `l` and `i` are global as you're not defining them using `var` or `let`. While this doesn't change much in your code, it could easily break things down the line, so it's best to ensure you use `var` or `let`:

```js
let dstring = "";
let estring = "";
let letter = "";
let letternum = 0;
let decodedtext = "";
let encodedtext = "";
let currentdt = "";
let currentcharat = 0;
const encoded = [ "lsdjf", "flwek", "sdlfj", "pjnse", "dsfnn", "dsnfe", "sjndv", "sdfew", "sdfjn", "sfnkh", "ådpfk", "qpwkd", "sorif", "efjnf", "pijgn", "sijfb", "feuwh", "renfv", "soduh", "osdnv", "ksdjn", "tonrn", "frjng", "fjenw", "fnkrj", "vrejl", "fgwei" ];
// updated to use `const`, avoids potentially overwriting `alphabet` unintentionally.
// Also remove `.split()` as it's not needed and added space
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '; 

function find(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
    if (input === encoded[i]) {
      return alphabet[i];
    }
  }
}
function encode() {
  estring = prompt("enter a string to encode, can only include non capital letters A-Z or SPACE");
  for (let i = 0; i < estring.length; i++) {
    letter = estring.charAt(i);
    if (letter.charCodeAt(0) === 32) {
      letternum = 26;
    } else {
       letternum = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 97
    } 
    encodedtext = encodedtext + encoded[letternum];
  }
  alert(encodedtext);
}
function decode() {
  decodedtext = "";
  dstring = prompt("enter a string to decode", "sdlfjpijgnpjnsedsfnn");
  for (let l = 0; l < dstring.length/5; l++) { // added `let`
    currentdt = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // added `let` 
      currentdt = currentdt + dstring.charAt((l*5)+i); // changed computation for offset
    }
    decodedtext = decodedtext + find(currentdt)
  }
  alert(decodedtext);
}
decode();
```